Security Implications of editable URLs on fetch requests
In my web app (js), I allow users to self host their own backend, and plug in their own api url to the client which will change subsequent network requests.
Ultimately wondering what the security implications are of allowing the user to override the url for all network request -- are xss/csrf concerns valid?. I'm aware that a browser extension could replicate this pretty easily, so assume it's safe.

As long as it only affects that user, there's no XSS problem. XSS is a concern when user A can customize what gets sent to user B.
